# ERROR '>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'str' in virt-mager

Tags: ubuntu, virt-manager

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 but `virt-install` doesn't work while my virt-manager version is 2.2.1

`$virt-manager --version 2.2.1`

i installed packages
`$sudo apt install libvirt-clients libvirt-daemon-system libvirt-daemon virtinst bridge-utils qemu qemu-kvm -y` &
`sudo apt install virtinst bridge-utils qemu qemu-kvm -y`

```
sudo virt-install --name ubuntu-guest20 --os-variant ubuntu20.04 --vcpus 2 --ram 2048 --location http://10.208.23.212/ --network bridge=virbr0,model=virtio --graphics none --extra-args='console=ttyS0,115200n8 serial'
```

it throws an error:
`ERROR    '>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'str'` in virt-mager